# python why win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId() PID returns a list

Tags: python, system, active-window

I try to find the path to executable of the current active window in python.
I am not familiar with system variables and did not know what i should do and i found a few solutions and practicing with them .

First i try to get current active window 
and finding the related PID and then the path.

```
import psutil
import win32process
import win32gui

window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(window)
active_window_path = psutil.Process(pid[1]).exe()


print("Active window: %s" % str(get_active_window()))
```

While i get PID with win32process it returns a list .Why ?
I had to select 1st element of the list to get the correct result .
isn't PID should be a integer ? Why it is returning a list ? And why 2nd element is correct and not first ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), which is a *Python* wrapper over *WINAPI*s.

- [[GitHub.MHammond]: win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32/win32process__GetWindowThreadProcessId_meth.html) wraps [[MS.Learn]: GetWindowThreadProcessId function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid)
- Returns a tuple consisting of 2 *int*s:

  - Thread ID (*TId*)
  - Process ID (*PId*)

Change (the relevant parts of) your code (not mandatory, just for readability) to:

```py
import win32process as wproc

# ...

tid, pid = wproc.GetWindowThreadProcessId(window)

active_window_path = psutil.Process(pid).exe()
```